# Batch file to find files in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a batch file to find if any files are present in the path `d:\Users\gladiator\Desktop\my docs`.
If any files are present, I need to trigger an email stating which are the files present in that path.

This is the snippet of my batch script.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "d:\Users\gladiator\Desktop\my docs"') do set MyVariable=%%F
echo %MyVariable%files are present
```

But this script is not displaying all the files present in that location.

Could someone help me to modify the script so as to display all the files present in the location?

Comment: Instead of `set MyVariable=%%F` do `echo/%%F` to get a list of all files; regard that your `echo` command appears outside of the loop...

Comment: Thanks aschipfl. That worked. and how can I display these listed files in a mail. i mean, can we trigger an email and list these are the files present..?

Comment: You do realise that your command is determining whether there is any matching content anywhere within the directory and all of its sub-directories, don't you? Regardless, it still does not provide the output, your question is about, _(all files present)_! Especially because the parenthesized command you're using `dir` is not using the appropriate options. Yours is currently outputting directories, it is also omitting any files which are hidden, system, or reparse points. That means that there may be files which are not included and the result would not be a true representaion of your intent.

Comment: To send e-mails you need to borrow or switch to another language since plain batch scripting is not capable of that. Anyway, this is not a free code writing, research nor tutorial service, so you will have to search for options on your own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to start a local environment before your loop, as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setlocal

Then, after you're done, use `endlocal`

When you expand the variable `MyVariable` use `!MyVariable!` which is how "delayed expansion" within a local environment works (rather than `%MyVariable%`).

Microsoft does not allow modification of an environment variable with `set variable=...` within a loop, without using "delayed expansion."

Here is an example with your code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "d:\Users\gladiator\Desktop\my docs"') do (
  set MyVariable=%%F
  echo !MyVariable! file is present
)

endlocal
```

This will at least allow you to see the files present. Beyond that I'm not sure what you wish to do once filenames are detected.

If you want to fill `MyVariable` with *all* files found, then you can do this

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set MyVariable=
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "d:\Users\gladiator\Desktop\my docs"') do (
  set MyVariable=!MyVariable! %%F
)
echo !MyVariable! files found
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks jpf.. But its not working. Sorry, i'm poor in batch scripting. so please help.

Comment: I've modified my answer to include code that works. Your code would not execute because of syntax errors. (for example, a parenthesis is required after `do`)